# Hadoop replica processing

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Does Hadoop process replicas also? For example worker node `i`, in `mapper` phase, processes the data stored on that machine only. After data (not replica, but original) is finished to be processed in `mapper` phase or maybe not finished, can there be a case that, machine `i` processes replica data stored on that machine? Or replica is used only when some node does off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, processing replicas also would happen on a specific scenario called **Speculative execution**.

If the `machine i` takes too much time to process the data block stored in that machine , then the job's Application master would start a duplicate parallel mapper against the another replica of the data block stored in a different machine. This new speculative mapper will run in the `machine j` where the replica is stored.

Whichever mapper completes the execution first, its outputs will be considered.The other slow running mapper and its resources will be removed.

by default, the Speculative execution is enabled. You could toggle this by modifying the below properties.

```
mapreduce.map.speculative
mapreduce.reduce.speculative
```

By any case, not more than one replica of the data block will be stored in the same machine. Every replica of the data block will be kept in different machines.

Answer (score 2):

The master node(jobtracker) may or may not pick the original data, in fact it doesn't maintain any info about out of the 3 replica which is original. Because when it saves the data it does a checksum verification on the file and saves it cleanly. Now when jobtracker wants to pick up a slot for the mapper, it takes so many things to account like number of free map slots, overhead of a tasktracker and other things. And last but not least data locality, so the closest node which satisfies almost all criteria will only be picked, it doesn't bother whether it is original or a replica and as mentioned even it doesn't maintain that identity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then how jobtracker ensures that different mappers dont process same replicas? Because replicas are stored probably on different machines, and jobtracker doesnt look for data originality, there is a possibility that different mappers can process replicas of same data.

Comment: So,what would be the issue. If there are 2 different mappers which process the same data then there is a chance that both the mappers may be reading from the same replica of data. It would just an extra overhead on that node.